# Open folder in another IP Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-permissions, file-sharing

My scenario is the following,

- I have an application, FreeFileSync, which is able to move all the data from a directory and subdirectories to another location.
- I have created a Windows Server 2012 Virtual Machine, in this VM i have created two users, Usuario1/us1 and Usuario2/us2.
- The VMWAre is in the IP 192.168.0.137 and the host is in the IP 192.168.0.37, th VMWAre name is PRUEBA
- The VMWare network connection is set as Bridged
- I have created two folders C:\Usuario1 and C:\Usuario2 in the VMWare
- The folder C:\Usuario1 is shared for Usuario1 and the folder C:\Usuario2 is shared for Usuario2
- I have Allowed the remote conections to the VM for these two users.
- When i try to connect using remote desktop connetion using Usuario1/us1 i can enter the computer and the folder C:\Usuario1 but not C:\Usuario2 ( which is ok)
- I can open as file explorer the VMWare, and i see this:
  [image]
- That's Ok, i see only the shared folders, now i try to open one of them and it asks for User/pass
  [image]

But, i enter the user and the pass and it doesn't opens the folder, it just asks again for username/pass

I would appreciate any help on how to open the folder Usuario1 from the file explorer, maybe i have to configure anything else in VMWare or in the host?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

This scenario means that you are using a wrong credentials.
Try to add the computer/domain name before the user name, for example:
user : `<host computer name>\<user name>`
password: `<the password you set>`

When you are using the way you sent the credentials , what the Microsoft SMB client does is add your `computer name` to the `user` in the `user name`.